# Only GROUP_CONCAT active functions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables, a **clients**, **persons**, **client_functions** and **functions** table.

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT 

P.number,
P.first_name
GROUP_CONCAT(F.description) AS Functions

FROM clients AS C

LEFT JOIN persons AS P ON P.id=C.id
LEFT JOIN client_functions as CF ON CF.client_id=C.id
LEFT JOIN functions AS F ON F.id=CF.function_id

WHERE P.person_type = 'client' AND P.company_id = 3

GROUP BY

P.number,
P.first_name
```

In my GROUP_CONCAT() i only want to group F.description if CF.archived = 0. Does anybody has an idea on how i can put a condition on the GROUP_CONCAT?

Current query results in:

```
--------------------------------------------
| 93    | Jan Lochtenberg   | PV,PV,PV,PV   |
| 94    | Chris van Eijk    | VP-I,VP,PV    |
| 95    | Gertrude Irene    | VP-I,PV,PV,PV |
| 96    | Wiekert Jager     | VP-I,PV       |
| 97    | Antonius Kode     | VP,VP-I,VP    |
| 98    | HansLelie         | PV,PV,PV      |
---------------------------------------------
```

But i only want to see the active functions

```
--------------------------------------------
| 93    | Jan Lochtenberg   | PV            |
| 94    | Chris van Eijk    | VP-I,VP,PV    |
| 95    | Gertrude Irene    | VP-I,PV       |
| 96    | Wiekert Jager     | VP-I,PV       |
| 97    | Antonius Kode     | VP,VP-I,VP    |
| 98    | HansLelie         | PV            |
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: group_concat(if(CF.archived = 0, F.description, ""))

Answer (score 1):

Your `where` is undoing some of your `left join`s.  In fact, you don't need the `clients` table at all.  Then you can put the filtering condition on functions in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT P.number, P.first_name, P.last_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(F.description) AS Functions
FROM persons P LEFT JOIN
     client_functions CF
     ON CF.client_id = p.id LEFT JOIN
     functions F
     ON F.id = CF.function_id AND cf.archived = 0
WHERE P.person_type = 'client' AND P.company_id = 3
GROUP BY P.number, P.first_name, P.last_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

> In my `GROUP_CONCAT()` i only want to group `F.description` if `CF.archived = 0`

Translated to SQL:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(CF.archived = 0, F.description, NULL))
```

The [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function ignores the `NULL` values. It returns, however, `NULL` if there isn't any not-`NULL` value to work with.